# Move a pixel through screen with swift

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm interested in having a VC with objects and others (static, not necessarily dynamic) and apart from that, I want to have a **pixel** (one or four, depending if it can be seen for the human eye) moving around the borders of the screen (so in the bounds).

I attach a photo of what I need:

[image: Mockup of what I need]

So I need that the "pixel" move indefinetely doing a square and I also need to know where it is to do something in my code (in swift)

Comment: Are you open to use a UIView instead of 'pixels'. It would look just the same and you can color it as well.

Comment: Yes no problem, I need something I can see but only if I know it is there. So that a normal person without knowing it doesn't notice that there's a pixel or whatever moving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a solution something to

**Swift 2**

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(4, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPointMake(0, 100)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1/4, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPointMake(100, 100)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2/4, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPointMake(100, 0)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(3/4, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    })

}, completion: nil)
```

**Swift 3,4,5**

```
UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: 4, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions.repeat, animations: { () -> Void in

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 0, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 1/4, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    })
    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 2/4, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 0)
    })

    UIView.addKeyframe(withRelativeStartTime: 3/4, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.aView.center = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    })

}, completion: nil)
```

The `CGPoint` values would the 4 corners of your screen where you want your `UIView` object to move.

Comment: Thanks, when I can I will try it and tell you something!

Comment: Hi, I have to put this in a view controller in the view did load or what? and for the aView I have to create a UIView with the object (point-pixel) I want? Thanks!

Comment: You can do this in the viewDidLoad of the viewController. You can create your UIView either by `UIView(frame)` or just create it in storyboard and get its reference.

Comment: Yes, I did it and it works but just the square 100x100. I think I will manage to do just the bounds, but one question now is, when ever I want, I would like to know where it's the view in that specific moment to do one thing or another. Thanks!