# Position of a UIView that's inside of the main UIView in a ViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm doing an app project in Swift, and I have an UIView moving inside the main View (the one that it's by default in the ViewController).

I want to know the exact position of the UIView when a button is pressed (X and Y).

I tried things like this but doesn't work for me:

```
let X = pointView.frame.origin.x + pointView.frame.origin.x;
let Y = pointView.frame.origin.y + pointView.frame.origin.y;
```

or

```
let frame = self.view.convertRect(self.view.frame, fromView:pointView)
```

The code I have at the moment:

```
    @IBAction func pressButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(4, delay: 0, options: UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions.Repeat, animations: { () -> Void in

            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0, relativeDuration: 1.5/4.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                //1
                self.pointView.center = CGPointMake(2, screenHeight-2)
                //2
            })
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(1.5/4, relativeDuration: 1/4, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.pointView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth-2, screenHeight-2)
            })
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(2.5/4, relativeDuration: 1.5/4.0, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.pointView.center = CGPointMake(screenWidth-2, 1)
            })
            //3
        }, completion: nil)
        //4
    }
```

Comment: what is the pointView ? If self.view is moving why you don't read his frame property directly ?

Comment: Self.view i thought it was the main view and PointView it's the view that I want to know where it is when the button is pressed and it's the one that is moving.

Answer (score 0):

Try this then:

```
let frame = pointView.superview?.convertRect(pointView.frame, toView: nil)
```

Sometime the view need his superView to find it's coordinates

Put it when you animation is finished

```
   UIView.animateWithDuration(1, animations: { () -> Void in
        //animation code
    }) { (success) -> Void in
        let frame = self.pointView.superview?.convertRect(self.pointView.frame, toView: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Hi, it doesn't work :( it tells me the position of the PointView in reference of the superview but the origin one, not the moved one. I have the PointView moving through the bounds of the screen and I want to know the position when the button is pressed. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide more code ? where are you converting the frame ? You have to put this line when your frame moved

Comment: Yes, the code that I use to move the view is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31011466/4496756

Comment: I don't think so. Where I have to put it?

Comment: In the completion block like I said, I edited my answer to show you an example

Comment: I've edited the question with my code of xCode I have. I tried to put it in the 1,2,3 and 4 numbers (commented with //) and if I put it in 1 it only tells me the start one, the 2 the end of the animation and the 3 and 4 don't tell me nothing. Any idea of how can I do it? Thanks!